# Put Downloaded Emails Back to POP3 Server

Tags: thunderbird, pop3, webmail

How can I put my downloaded emails back to my POP3 server? I want it to appear like how it was sent originally. I made a mistake of setting Thunderbird to delete my server-side emails and keep only the local ones. Now I need to re-upload it back to my webmail. How do I go about doing this?

The Mailredirect Extension is not compatible with my current Thunderbird so I don't think that trick will be possible.

I'm using Windows Live Mail as a mail service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POP3 does not allow for upload of messages, so using only POP3 this is impossible.

If you can use IMAP, you could use that to upload the mail. Otherwise, your only option is something like Mailredirect, to resend the mail.

Note that there is a version of Mailredirect on the author's homepage:

http://mailredirect.mozdev.org/

In the long run, you might want to consider switching to IMAP. It offers several nice features in addition to POP3. If your provider does not offer it, you may have to switch providers (you could still redirect your mail to keep your address).

Comment: Hmm... every 10 messages or so that I redirect Windows Live prompts me to login to my mail account and type a certain captcha, would i have to do this for all of my 500+ emails? :(

Comment: Quite possible, but that's up to Windows Live to decide. It's probably a defence against mass mailing, or abuse of your email address...

Comment: @sleske it feels to me more like Windows Live using a bad protocol (IMAP vs POP3) to encourage more website hits. Live allows ActiveSync (Exchange - feature wise more like IMAP) but only for mobile and Outlook.